# On Bibliography style- commas and italics

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, natbib

I am working on my thesis for which I need to properly write the bibliography. I separately made a .bib file and then entered the entries like the following.

```
@article{Garside,
author = {Garside, F.},
year = {1969},
month = {01},
pages = {235-254},
title = {The braid group and other groups},
volume = {20},
journal = {Quarterly Journal of Mathematics}
```

}

However, this is giving me the following output.
[image]

I want
a) the title to get italicised and b) the names of authors and titles, etc, to be separated by commas and not full stops as in the picture.
Changing the bibliography style did not work. Kindly help me with this!

Comment: Welcome toTeX.SX! Could you consider using biblatex?

Comment: Which bibliography style(s) have you tried so far?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You've only indicated how you would like to format entries of type `@article`. What are your formatting requirements for the entry types `@book`, `@techreport`, `@inproceedings`, `@unpublished`, and `@misc`, to name but a few other common entry types?

Comment: Off-topic: `month = {01}` isn't correct. It should be `month = jan`.